# How to implement Promise.any with a mapped return type similar to Promise.all?

Tags: typescript, promise, mapped-types

Promise.all resolves to an array of results corresponding with the array of Promises passed to the method. See the declaration for Promise.all in the ES2015 lib:

```js
all<T extends readonly unknown[] | []>(values: T): Promise<{ -readonly [P in keyof T]: Awaited<T[P]> | undefined }>;
```

The mapped type on the return is very useful. I want to write a variant of Promise.any that has a similar return type. This is as far as I've gotten:

```js
export async function any<T extends readonly unknown[]>(
  proms: T,
): Promise<{ -readonly [P in keyof T]: Awaited<T[P]> }> {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < proms.length; i++) {
      // @ts-ignore: type unknown doesn't have .then
      proms[i].then(
        // @ts-ignore: subresult is type any
        (subresult) => { 
          const all_results = new Array(proms.length); 
          all_results[i] = subresult;
          // @ts-ignore: all_results does not match the return type
          res(all_results);
        },
        rej,
      );
    }
  });
}
```

First, when I change the `T` generic to `extends readonly Promise<unknown>[]` the mapped type no longer works correctly, such that `[first, second]` in the following example are no longer typed as `[string, number]` but `[string | number, string | number]` which defeats the purpose of using the mapped type.

```js
async function test() {
  let [ first, second ] = await any([
    Promise.resolve('abc'),
    Promise.resolve(1000)
  ])
}
```

Secondly, I don't see any interface on arrays that exposes a mapped type, which would enable me to satisfy the return type TS expects.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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)

Comment: would [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdAB0m) answer your question?

Comment: @TobiasS. that is certainly alot closer than my effort. Is there any way to remove that last ts-ignore though? Also, I made an edit to the return type in the example on the question.

Comment: TypeScript is often not able to understand complex return types like mapped types or conditional in function implementations. I would go for a type assertion: https://tsplay.dev/N71JBW